# Date field is being presented as integer

Tags: elasticsearch, date, json, kibana

I have an `Elastic Stack` server (on `Hyper-v`) that is ingesting data via a `logstash` `exec` command and performing analytics on it. Everything is working great except a date field that is being displayed as a number.

How do I get `logstash`, `Elasticsearch` or `Kibana` to recognize the field s a date instead of a number?

The data is `Unix epoch` time in `milliseconds`.

---

### Code:

Data outputted by the `python` file is in `JSON` format. No real processing is taking place until it hits `elasticsearch`.

Logstash config:

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "/home/elliot/BullhornConnector.py JobOrder isOpen,webResponses,submissions,sendouts,interviews,placements,address,numOpenings,employmentType,owner,title,clientCorporation"
    interval => 60
    codec => json
    tags => ["JobOrder"]
  }
  exec {
    command => "/home/elliot/BullhornConnector.py Lead owner,leadSource,firstName,lastName,status,dateAdded"
    interval => 60
    codec => json
    tags => ["Lead"]
  }
  exec {
    command => "/home/elliot/BullhornConnector.py Opportunity owner,isOpen,dealValue,weightedDealValue,clientCorporation,status"
    interval => 60
    codec => json
    tags => ["Opportunity"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

---

### Screen shots:

Here is a screenshot of the raw data:
[image: Raw data display]

Index pattern overview page:
[image: Data overview on index patterns page]

Detailed view of the field:
[image: Setting does not allow me to change it.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out:
What you need to do is use a filter plugin in logstash, specifically the [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) plugin.

Here is the snippet that I added to my logstash config:

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "dateAdded", "UNIX_MS" ]
    target => "dateAddedCorrected"
  }
}
```

Comment: In fact, this is the way to go if you want dateAdded to be the logstash event timestamp. If it's just a date field but not your timestamp, you must use a mapping template.

Comment: It turns out that this filter plugin can output to a different field than the time stamp, see the target section? That outputs to a different field that is date type.

Answer (score 3):

If I read correctly the ElasticSearch documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

```
JSON doesn’t have a date datatype, so dates in Elasticsearch can either be:

strings containing formatted dates, e.g. "2015-01-01" or "2015/01/01 12:10:30".
a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.
an integer representing seconds-since-the-epoch.
```

So your dateAdded field represented as an "number" data type is logical: Elasticsearch simply translated a JSON number to an ES number.

If I look at my own ELK instance, I found that the "timestamp" field is represented as a "date" data type. It's done automatically by logstash.

Behind the scene, logstash manage a 'mapping template' to define ES fields data types. In your case, it naively translate the date type from JSON and in the case of the timestamp it knows that it's a date so explicitely define it .

So what you need to do is define a mapping template and use logstash to push it to ES with your data.

ES mapping doc is here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html and Logstash can manage it with manage_template and template in elasticsearch output https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template. An introduction to AS mapping https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-mapping-introduction.

You can also look at the mapping actually being in use with

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/<index>/_mapping?pretty'
```

Comment: ok, will try. Thanks for the info. Can you provide an example of a template?

Comment: Nvm, here is an example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_example_mapping

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It did not work for me. You can see what worked for me in my answer. Thank you again for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, because I am not familiar with the platforms and programs you are talking about.  However, in your screenshot you stated you changed the data type to Duration, but it looks like the data type is still 'number', and the 'format' is duration.  If I had to continue to guess, I'd say that your platform is still trying to serialize your field there as a number, because its data type is still 'number'.  Change that type to 'date' like the @timestamp field at the top of the screenshot, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to do that. Thanks for your input :-)